# Unused argument error with ggplot position_dodge(preserve = "single")

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am getting error when trying to use the preserve argument to position_dodge() described [here](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_dodge.html) in the ggplot documentation.

```
ggplot(
       mtcars,
       aes(
           factor(cyl),
           fill = factor(vs)
           )
        ) +
 geom_bar(position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"))
```

Error in position_dodge(preserve = "single") : 
  unused argument (preserve = "single")

I am using R version 3.4.1 and ggplot2 version 2.2.1

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: The error is quite clear actually. The issue is that `preserve` is not an argument to `position_dodge`. Try `?position_dodge` and you will see that the only argument is `width`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `preserve` argument is present in the development version of `ggplot2` but for the moment only in the function `position_dodge2()` and not in the normal `position_dodge()` function. This link shows how I found that information: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=preserve&type=

It's unclear to me why the online documentation (http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/index.html) shows `preserve` as a current, usable feature.

If you really want to use this function you could try installing the development version. I have no idea if that would be a good idea or not!

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")
```