# Updating to new position_dodge() command with preserve argument

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to run some code that uses the `position_dodge()` function with the preserve = "single" argument. However, I receive the following error:

`Error in position_dodge(preserve = "single") : 
  unused argument (preserve = "single")`

I tried to use what was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49545514/unused-argument-error-with-ggplot-position-dodgepreserve-single) to download the newest ggplot 2.2.1.900, but I am hit with another error when I try to load the package:

`Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace ‘rlang’ 0.1.6 is already loaded, but >= 0.2.0.9001 is required
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’`

Any ideas how I can get the updated `position_dodge()` running?

Comment: try getting the development `rlang` as suggested with `devtools::install_github("r-lib/rlang")`?

Comment: Just tried that and hit with `Error in unloadNamespace(package) : 
  namespace ‘rlang’ is imported by ‘tidyr’, ‘tibble’, ‘purrr’ so cannot be unloaded
Error in library(rlang) : 
  Package ‘rlang’ version 0.1.6 cannot be unloaded`

Comment: There is a manual work around for the `preserve = single` command that I can try, just frustrating to not be able to get this package updated.

Comment: These errors e.g. `namespace ‘rlang’ is imported` imply you are trying to update packages when they are loaded. Try updating in a clean R session

Comment: @JackBrookes that worked! Great... Thanks!